# Good Mnemonic to remember few radicals

Tags: meaning, etymology

隶 lì to catch, Servant
麦 mài wheat, barley

Can anyone suggest unique, etymologically correct mnemonic for the above radicals? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 隶: hold an ox tail on the right hand to catch a slave

隶 is a 會意字 (ideogrammic compounds).
[image]
The upper part is 象形字 (Pictogram) for 又，which upon creation meant right hand. You can see clearly the thumb, the middle finger and the index finger.
[image]

The lower part is ox tail. The four side strokes are hair on the tail. Thus, the **glyph pictures that someone is holding ox tail on his right hand.**

The 會意 implication of the glyph comes then naturally from two questions: **what is he doing by holding ox tail on his right hand? The answer is to successfully catch someone.** This is the first meaning (also extended to mean 及, reach).  Now it's written as 逮 dai4. The extra part 夊 sui1 means to walk. The second question is **who is caught? The answer is slave.** This is the second meaning, now pronounced as li4.

---

### 麥：(auspicious) wheat comes (from the almighty sky)

麥 mai4 was originally written as 來 lai2.
[image]
[image]

來 is a 象形字 (pictogram), meaning wheat. The horizontal stroke was originally added as a left-falling stroke, intensifying the meaning of ear of wheat.

Ancient Chinese thought 瑞麥天來, which meaning **auspicious wheat comes from the almighty**. Thus this glyph was then used to mean to come. Later this meaning gained dominance and another glyph 麥 was created to refer to its original meaning, wheat. The added part is a foot plate 夊, concreting the thought of 瑞麥天來.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation of etymology and etymological correct mnemonic.

Comment: 麥：auspicious wheat comes from the almighty sky => Could you please elaborate to strict to my mind? where is sky or auspicious in this char?

Comment: I put in two brackets: (auspicious) wheat comes (from the almighty sky). It's not explicitly encoded. But the concept is corroborated with other glyph as well as classical documents.

Comment: Lilysirius has a very comprehensive answer.  You can also recognize that 来 was originally just a sound loan of “wheat.”  To distinguish the meanings, they added roots to the character for wheat 麦. It’s also possible that the characters were meant in reverse so that a foot was added to the meaning of “come,” but because of the stark difference in frequency, the usage got switched again so that 麦 was again used to mean “wheat.”